# for bounded series $x_n$, prove that $\limsup(1/x_n) = 1/ \liminf( x_n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Stuck on a proof about series:
i know that $ 0 < a \leq x_n \leq b, $

$a$ and $b$ are real numbers (not infinite)

and from this it follows that $1/x_n$ is also bounded by $1/b$ and $1/a,$  which are positive.

How can i prove that $ \limsup( 1/x_n ) = 1 /  \liminf(x_n) ?$

I know that $\limsup(x_n) = -\liminf(- x_n) $

and by Bolzano-Weierstraas every bounded set has a converging subset..
But i can't seem to think of a solution to this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has this to do with series? There are no series in the statement of the problem.

Comment: This is true if and only if $\{x_n\}$ converges.

Comment: Nevermind, the question is a duplicate of this one:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164104/lim-sup1-over-x-n-1-over-lim-inf-x-n
Thanks anyway